# Android O 8.0.0 Having issue and crashes on calling sync() method of CookieSyncManager

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Seen the log as follows only specific to Android "O" 8 Google Pixel :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathNative(AssetManager.java)
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathInternal(AssetManager.java:689)
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.addAssetPathAsSharedLibrary(AssetManager.java:684)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:407)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
       at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
       at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.sync(CookieSyncManager.java:112)
```

Interestingly the issue is there on a call doing

```
android.webkit.CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncManager.sync();
```

As per the document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html 
the call to sync() is deprecated and should call to  flush() instead. but the method is just deprecated.
On having an internal check with code of `CookieSyncManager` found that it does as follows

```
/**
     * sync() forces sync manager to sync now
     * @deprecated Use {@link CookieManager#flush} instead.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void sync() {
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    }
```

Interested to know the cause of this failure as Crashlytics shows a big number of crashes on the same.

Comment: I think cookieSyncManager is null. debug your code and check this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you're trying to create the class instance it fails. That's because they changed the instance contructor from:

```
private CookieSyncManager() {
        super("CookieSyncManager");
    }
```

too:

```
private CookieSyncManager() {
        super(null, null);
    }
```

it's also why you're getting the NullPointerException